# What is the transformation order when using the Transform Class?

Tags: unity

I am currently using Unity 5.5 for the first time in a project and I've got some problems regarding transformations.

I've got a background in more general 3D graphics meaning that I'm used to manually manage scene graphs and matrix transformation orders.

My greatest problem when moving to Unity, and using their built in Transform Class, is that I can't find any information regarding the transformation order of rotation, localrotation, scaling, localscaling, position and localposition.

I can't find any good information of this and It's driving me slightly mad.

TL;DR: What's the transformation order of the Transform class?

Comment: My guess is they follow the convention most game engines use which `Translation * Rotation * Scale` and with the local stuff I would guess `(LocalTranslation * WorldTranslation) * (LocalRotation * WorldRotation) * (LocalScaling * WorldScaling)`

Answer (score 12):

1. Local scale (`localScale`)
2. Local rotation (`localRotation`)

   [If using Euler angles, they're applied as rotations about the world axes in the order](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html):

   1. Roll (rotation about the world z axis)
   2. Pitch (rotation about the world x axis)
   3. Yaw (rotation about the world y axis)

   (Or, if you prefer to think of rotations happening around local axes, it's...)

   1. Yaw (rotation about the local y axis)
   2. Pitch (rotation about *the resulting* local x axis)
   3. Roll (rotation about *the resulting* local z axis)
3. Local translation (`localPosition`)
4. Parent's local transforms, in the same order as above

Repeat all the way to the root of the transform hierarchy.

The non-local parameters, `lossyScale`, `rotation`, `position`, represent the net effect of this entire transformation chain (`lossyScale` being a "lossy" approximation since, by the time we've combined several scales and rotations, the resulting scale is not guaranteed to be axis-aligned, so it might no longer be well represented by a Vector3)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the Inspector tutorial here https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/inspector

and take a look here
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html

You have all the information needed visually about:

- Transform position (X, Y, Z)
- Transform rotation as euler angles (X, Y, Z)
- Transform scale (again, X, Y, Z)

Comment: While these references are useful, this answer doesn't actually describe the order in which transformations are applied (which matters because a number of transformations are non-commutative — doing the same operations in a different order can give different results). Unity has a particular convention for the order in which its various transform properties stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could print out the `localToWorldMatrix`.  If the rightmost/4th column contains `transform.position`, then you know the translation was applied last, i.e.

```
localToWorldMatrix = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix !=  rotationMatrix * translationMatrix
```